# Divisor function for not relatively prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is [well known](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sigma_Function_is_Multiplicative) that the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}d, n\in\mathbb{N}$ is multiplicative, i.e. if $\textrm{gcd}\{m,n\}=1$, then $\sigma(mn)=\sigma(m)\sigma(n)$.

For general $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, is there an easy way to modify the prove to see that $\sigma(mn)\leq \sigma(m)\sigma(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sigma(m)\sigma(n) = \bigg(\sum_{d_1 \mid m} d_1 \bigg) \cdot  \bigg(\sum_{d_2 \mid n} d_2 \bigg)=\sum_{d_1 \mid m \space {;} \space d_2 \mid n}d_1d_2 \geqslant \sum_{d \mid mn} d = \sigma(mn)$$

Note that here, every $d_1$ and $d_2$ multiply to correspond to some divisor $d \mid mn$. It is clear that every divisor of $mn$ can be written in this way such that $d_1 \mid m$ and $d_2 \mid n$.

The inequality occurs when this representation is not unique. When $\gcd(m,n)=1$, you can use the fact that the intersection of prime factors of $m$ and $n$ being null to show that there is exactly one way to write every $d$ as $d_1d_2$. However, if $\gcd(m,n)>1$, note that when $d=mn$, we have:
$$(d_1,d_2)=(m,n),\bigg(\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)},n\gcd(m,n) \bigg)$$
are two different representations, making the inequality strict i.e. equality only occurs when $\gcd(m,n)=1$.